# Color replacing in the indexed image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, image-editing

I have 8-bit indexed BMP image. How can replace some colors in it using Photoshop (13.1.2) but obligatory making sure/constraining that the new colors will be taken taken ONLY from the image palette?